# How to have checkbox remove 'required' validation in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I am wondering how I can have a checkbox remove the 'required' validation for a specific radio group in a form.

If the checkbox is checked, I don't want the 'required' attribute to be enforced.

Here is an example of my existing HTML: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PrbOPK

```
<label for="Group1_notRequired">Check here to make radio buttons in Gorup 1 NOT required:</label> <input id="Group1_notRequired" name="Group1_notRequired" type="checkbox" value="Group1_notRequired" />
<br><br><br>
<label><input name="Group1" required="" type="radio" value="Option1" />Group 1 Option 1</label>
<label><input name="Group1" required="" type="radio" value="Option2" />Group 1 Option 2</label>
<br><br><br>
<label><input name="Group2" required="" type="radio" value="Option1" />Group 2 Option 1</label>
<label><input name="Group2" required="" type="radio" value="Option2" />Group 2 Option 2</label>
```

Comment: `$('TARGET').prop('required',false)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.removeAttr()](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) and [.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) to remove/add an attribute:

```js
$('#Group1_notRequired').on('change', function(e) {
    if (this.checked == true) {
        $('[name="Group1"]').removeAttr('required');
    } else {
        $('[name="Group1"]').attr('required', '');
    }
    console.log($('[name="Group1"]').parent()[0].outerHTML);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="Group1_notRequired">Check here to make radio buttons in Gorup 1 NOT required:</label> <input id="Group1_notRequired" name="Group1_notRequired" type="checkbox" value="Group1_notRequired" />

<br><br><br>

<label><input name="Group1" required="" type="radio" value="Option1" />Group 1 Option 1</label>
<label><input name="Group1" required="" type="radio" value="Option2" />Group 1 Option 2</label>

<br><br><br>

<label><input name="Group2" required="" type="radio" value="Option1" />Group 2 Option 1</label>
<label><input name="Group2" required="" type="radio" value="Option2" />Group 2 Option 2</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion:

```
$radioG1 = $('[name="Group1"]')
$cbxG1 = $('#Group1_notRequired')

$cbxG1.change(function() {
  $radioG1.prop("required", !this.checked)
})
```